# JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

So classic problem, but having a horrible time on finding the actual cause. Typically when I see this error it's because the jQuery reference is after code requiring it, or back jQuery link, or jQuery conflict, etc... so far none of those appear to be the case. Unfortunately seeking out the solution to this problem has lead me to post after post of such cases. I'm sure my problem here is equally as simple, but over an hour of hunting, still no luck...

Edit: Additional information...
The solution file (which I've recreated multiple times trying to figure this out. Is a JavaScript Windows Store Blank App template and I'm doing this in Visual studio. The only references files is Windows Library for javascript 1.0, I have tried deleting this to test as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>HTML5 Canvas Template</title>
        <style>
            /* styles here */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">
            <p>Canvas not supported.</p>
        </canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var canvas = $("#myCanvas").get(0);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                function renderContent()
                {
                    // we'll do our drawing here...
                }

                renderContent();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried a different source link?

Comment: I just tried your code and I'm not getting that error.

Comment: I have tried a different source link (3 actually) but thanks for checking

icanc - man I hate those kind of situations... but that does tell me the problem isn't limited to the code itself, perhaps something in the nature of my solution is at fault.

Comment: What if you put the reference to jQuery in the <head> tag?

Comment: Tried that, no luck, but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's states that **`JQuery`** referred URL is not correct

Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was able to access the file at my previous link, but went ahead and replaced it with the URL for this one, confirming I could access it as well. But I'm still getting an error as if I have no reference to jQuery present :( (I added the missing "http:" on the front of it, but did try it with out for the heck of it)

Edit: more details

Comment: I think this is http://devhammer.net/blog/exploring-html5-canvas-part-1---introduction what you're using try to download the complete file from the link and test it.

Comment: That's the exact set of tutorials I'm working on to learn canvas, and while I see many useful links there I don't see a link for the final code. He does offer up the JSFIDDLE with code in it, but if you look at the HTML the script tags are completely omitted which is my current suspicion is related to this problem. I've looked over three times just to make sure I didn't miss the download link :(

Comment: Here is the fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/NqmkC/1/ with the JQuery link I provided

Comment: Thank you, I tried using it, same problem fails the moment it his the $(document).ready() as undefined. It's got to be something with the solution itself, I've been digging all over the developer forums specific for this as well, still coming up empty handed.

Comment: Or you can download it from jquery site or the other and keep the JQuery.min.js in a seperate js folder and try to refer it..Sometimes if your system is not connected to the internet it fails..

Comment: Well that fixed it! (Sorry it took so long, I tried to link you provided but seems 1.9.1 causes some other errors, reverting to 1.7.1 which is what was used in the tutorial resolved that, no errors) :D I find it rather odd though, I'm writing this comment on the computer I'm doing this all on, so needless to say internet connectivity isn't at fault here, but I digress it solved my problem thank you :)

Edit: Marked it as an answer because apparently I'm a nublet and mixed up marking answered with upvoting it.

Comment: Other Thing I Would like to suggest is keep a downloaded copy of jQuery in Code instead of calling from some site. This will improve you performance and also but JQuery <sscript></script> tags within Head Section

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything listed above and nothing seems to work until I put this string

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the head section of the HTML file. So here's how it looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- jQuery Reference -->
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />


    <title>some title</title>

</head>
<body>
...
```

And the js file is located at a level below in the folder 'scripts'.
Finally, the error is gone and what a relief!

Comment: bless your soul! Spent the whole day trying to figure out what i was doing wrong. I had the exact same situation and this was it! Thank you.

Comment: Had same problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good thing to do because the browser will block rendering until the JavaScript is downloaded.  Google Page Speed will tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I was rendering my page over https but I was trying to request the JQuery file over http, which is blocked by many browsers for security reasons.

My fix was to change this...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

...to this...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

This causes the browser to download JQuery using the same protocol (http or https) as the page being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my clients had this problem, because apparently they blocked loading Javascript from 3rd party sites. So now I always use the following code to include jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.jQuery || 
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

This makes sure, that even if my client blocks loading the Javascript file from the CDN domain, the client still downloads the file from my own server, which is not blocked by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Anover variant, in my case - I was forced to use proxy. So **- IE11--> InternetOptions --> Connections-->LANSettings-Proxy Server--> UseProxyServer** -  should be checked.
 Also check awailability of jQUery script source, my worked variant in VS2012 -  -just like in top example

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this same error code:

> (Error: 'generateText' is undefined)

...on the code

`var bodyText=["The....now."]`

I discovered on my text-editor(Notepad++), when typing many lines of text in the directly above the variable `bodyText`, if I didn't hit `return carriage` (enter==>WordWrap is off) just kept typing w/o `return carriage` and let the editor adjust text it worked?

Must be in the settings of Notepad++??