# Receiving '$' is undefined when trying to create a CSS drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a drop down menu on an HTML page using some CSS and JavaScript. The CSS seems to work fine but the JS returns a `'$' is undefined`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have this set up to open the web page when a button is clicked in the CRM 2011 ribbon. Currently it's set up to just run locally though.

HTML:

```
<html>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OpportunityStyleSheet.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createRecord.js"></script>  
</header>

<body>
    <h3>Select your Products</h3>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

function createRecord() {
alert("Button Pressed");
}
```

The `createRecord()` function does work and shows the correct alert. Thanks for any help!

Error Message.
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>'$' is undefined</Message>
   <Line>6</Line>
   <URL>/_common/global.ashx?ver=66087337</URL>
   <PageURL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=3&id=%7b515C22D0-7524-E311-8980-12A32B1E376A%7d&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1395165209284</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");$v_0.text=scriptContent}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptFile){var$v_0=scriptFile.toString();if(this.$4W_1($v_0))return;var$v_1=this.fetchExternalFile($v_0);this.addIncludeInline(container,$v_1,$v_0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(uri,useInlineScripts,scriptLoaded){if(uri.get_path().toUpperCase()==="/_STATIC/_COMMON/SCRIPTS/GLOBAL.JS")uri=Mscrm.CrmUri.create("/_common/global.ashx");if(useInlineScripts)Mscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalSync(null,uri);elseMscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalCallback(null,uri,scriptLoaded)}</Function>
    <Function>loadWebResourceScript(sScriptSrc,sId)</Function>
    <Function>LoadJsScripts()</Function>
    <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){executeAction(action);executeActionQueue()}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2; BOIE9;ENUS)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-us</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>en-us</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>en-us</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1600x900</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Outlook Laptop - Online</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2014-03-18T11:53:30</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{AACB118A-823E-4A12-BFCD-190E5E9BE731}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{E200F73B-57CC-E111-B35F-12A32B1E376A}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>5.0.9690.3731</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>

<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>'$' is undefined</Message>
   <Line>6</Line>
   <URL>/_common/global.ashx?ver=66087337</URL>
   <PageURL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=3&id=%7b515C22D0-7524-E311-8980-12A32B1E376A%7d&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1395165209284</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");$v_0.text=scriptContent}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptFile){var$v_0=scriptFile.toString();if(this.$4W_1($v_0))return;var$v_1=this.fetchExternalFile($v_0);this.addIncludeInline(container,$v_1,$v_0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(uri,useInlineScripts,scriptLoaded){if(uri.get_path().toUpperCase()==="/_STATIC/_COMMON/SCRIPTS/GLOBAL.JS")uri=Mscrm.CrmUri.create("/_common/global.ashx");if(useInlineScripts)Mscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalSync(null,uri);elseMscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalCallback(null,uri,scriptLoaded)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3){Mscrm.CrmHeader.setScriptFile(Mscrm.CrmUri.create($p1),true);for(var$v_0=window,$v_1=$p0.split("."),$v_2=0;$v_2<$v_1.length;$v_2++)if($v_0)$v_0=$v_0[$v_1[$v_2]];if(!IsNull($v_0)&&typeof$v_0===Mscrm.TypeNames.functionType){var$v_3=this.$CN_1($p2,$p3);return$v_0.apply(null,$v_3)}returnnull}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3){var$v_0=this.getCommandDefinition($p0,$p1);if(IsNull($v_0)||IsNull($v_0.Actions))returnfalse;for(var$v_1=0;$v_1<$v_0.Actions.length;$v_1++){var$v_2=$v_0.Actions[$v_1];switch($v_2.ActionType){case2:this.$DF_1($v_2.Attributes);break;case3:var$v_3=$v_2.Attributes;this.$9z_1($v_3.FunctionName,$v_3.Library,$v_2.Parameters,$p2);break;case1:this.$DG_1($v_2.Attributes,$v_2.Parameters);break}}returntrue}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){var$v_0=this.parseCommandFromRibbon($p0),$v_1=this.$7w_1($v_0.command,$v_0.entityLogicalName,$p1,$p2),$v_2=$p1;if(!IsNull($v_2)&&!isNullOrEmptyString($v_2.PopulationXML)&&!$v_2.SuppressCommandIncludes){var$v_3=null;if($v_0.entityContext==="Form"){var$v_4=$find("crmFormSelector");if($v_4)$v_3=$v_4.get_currentFormId()}$v_2.PopulationXML=this.$Ep_1($v_2.PopulationXML,$v_0.entityLogicalName,$v_3)}return$v_1}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){if(this.$1w_1&&!this.$1w_1.$3m_1)returnthis.$1w_1.handleCommand($p0,$p1,$p2);returnfalse}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(handler,commandId,properties,sequenceNumber){returnhandler.handleCommand(commandId,properties,sequenceNumber)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2){var$v_0=this.$2S_0[$p0];if(CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($v_0))returnfalse;elseif(Array.isInstanceOfType($v_0)){for(var$v_1=$v_0,$v_2=false,$v_3=0;$v_3<$v_1.length;$v_3++){var$v_4=$v_1[$v_3];if(this.callCommandHandler($v_4,$p0,$p1,$p2))$v_2=true}return$v_2}elsereturnthis.callCommandHandler($v_0,$p0,$p1,$p2)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(commandId,properties){returnthis.$DE_0(commandId,properties,this.getNextSequenceNumber())}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(commandId,properties,commandInfo,root){returnthis.$10_1.executeCommand(commandId,properties)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){if(CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($p0.$4_1))return;$p0.$7U_1=this.$DU_1();var$v_0=$p0.get_commandInfo();$v_0.CommandId=$p0.$4_1;$v_0.RootId=this.$4_0;$v_0.RootType=this.get_rootType();!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$26_1)&&this.$26_1.executeRootCommand($p0.$4_1,$p0.$34_1,$v_0,this)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$7w_1($p0);returntrue}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){if($p0.$I_1!==11){$p0.get_commandInfo().RootLocation=$p0.$I_1===2?"UpperRibbon":"LowerRibbon";if($p0.$I_1===2){var$v_0=$p0.$34_1;$p0.get_commandInfo().TabId=$v_0.NewContextId}}returnCUI.Root.prototype.$2p_0.call(this,$p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){this.$2p_0($p0)&&!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$M_0)&&this.$M_0.$B0_0($p0);this.$Ao_0($p0)}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2; BOIE9;ENUS)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-us</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>en-us</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>en-us</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1600x900</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Outlook Laptop - Online</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2014-03-18T11:53:33</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{AACB118A-823E-4A12-BFCD-190E5E9BE731}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{E200F73B-57CC-E111-B35F-12A32B1E376A}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>5.0.9690.3731</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Comment: JSfiddle required. Are you loading Jquery?

Comment: Did you google your issue? https://www.google.com/search?q=%27%24%27+is+undefined

Comment: How are you running the page? from a web server or from `file://`? - Also createRecord will work regardless, as it's vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Change the script src from //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js  to  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Yes I Googled my question first before posting this. I've tried all mentioned jscript library notations they all return the same issue. Here is the error message in greater detail. I am posting it in the original post since I can't fit in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to append **http:** while running locally, later it can be removed since "//" will prefix approx protocol.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Its always good to have head, meta, title tags mentioned in each document. Not related to above issue. this is clean and proper way of writing. :)

**Your html document...as requested:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OpportunityStyleSheet.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createRecord.js"></script>  

</head>

<body>
<h3>Select your Products</h3>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
});
function createRecord() {
alert("Button Pressed");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers,

Ashok

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I will keep the tags comment in mind. I have tried referencing the jscript library many different ways. I receive the same error back each time. I posted the full message in the original post. Thanks for your help. I change out all the css and jscript references for the "http://crmserver" references. One of which is a jquery that does work on other web resources I have running in the CRM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the proper JQuery library loaded. Please provide us with full head section.

Take a look at this topic: [JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971394/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined) for similar problem.

Added:
I can see the head section now - "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" is not the proper library url - add http: to it.

Comment: `//` means protocol `relative`/`agnostic`, so will work on `http` and `https`, but won't work when you run it directly from the `file://` protocol.

Comment: The fix will solve the problem, but the explanation is not correct. `"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"` is the proper url, assuming you run your code from a webserver (which you should always do)

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply. I actually did see that question you posted the link to prior to asking this question. It returns the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. The jscript library needs to be called twice basically. Once in the html file (like you all suggested above) and again on the CRM entity that the function is running off of. I didn't think this needed to happen because nothing was being called until the button was clicked that called the function to show the webpage. However, apparently I was wrong.

Thank you everyone for your help and comments.