# Adding SCSS and JS file to html, not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, web-deployment

I have been trying to add this "burger" style menu to a website and and getting stuck because the burger animation is not playing on the click.

Menu is here: https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/hyFAD

I put the 'compiled' SCSS code into the css file and linked it like I'd like any other css file.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```js
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
* {
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #d9e4ea;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #566973;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#menu-toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu-toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#menu-toggle #hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-toggle #hamburger span {
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#menu-toggle #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
#menu-toggle #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.625s;
}
#menu-toggle #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.75s;
}
#menu-toggle #cross {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu-toggle #cross span:nth-child(1) {
  height: 0%;
  width: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 48px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#menu-toggle #cross span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 48px;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

#menu-toggle.open #hamburger span {
  width: 0%;
}
#menu-toggle.open #hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#menu-toggle.open #hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.125s;
}
#menu-toggle.open #hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
#menu-toggle.open #cross span:nth-child(1) {
  height: 80%;
  transition-delay: 0.625s;
}
#menu-toggle.open #cross span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
  transition-delay: 0.375s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-toggle">
  <div id="hamburger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="cross">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the relationship in the file structure?

Comment: They're all in the same folder. This code works perfectly on Codepen.io but when I try to use it in my own projects the button doesn't work.

Comment: If it's in the same folder (a sibling) then what you listed would work. A thing to try would be to use `../style.css` to see if it's actually up one level. Sometimes relative sources can be a pain. Without actually seeing the structure, it's hard to tell. Just something to try in the meantime. :)

Comment: u have to add jquery library as referance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971394/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing everything correct here. Probably, the $ object you are using requires a library to be invoked.

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

The syntax you are using is actually from a library named jQuery which is build over JavaScript and provides such utilities to help us write lesser and better code.

For this just search for jQuery CDN on internet. Open the first link and go to jQuery 3.x minified, a popup will appear and copy the script and place it just before closing your body tag.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

Further, if you are not willing to use jQuery. This is how you would write in native JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("menu-toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(this.classList[0] === 'open'){
     this.classList.remove('open');
  }
  else {
     this.classList.add('open');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.