# Javascript or jquery change fields value by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I use these codes to change the value of a field. Only the first two lines run, I tried the rest of the code but it did not work and sometimes the message "*Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*" is displayed on the console.

[image: Error displayed on console]

```
document.getElementsByName('tmcp_textfield_6').value = Pak;
document.getElementById("tmcp_textfield_116202d52cbd078").value = Pak;
$("input[name='tmcp_textfield_6']").val(Pak);
document.getElementsByName("tmcp_textfield_6").value = 100;
document.getElementByname("tmcp_textfield_6").value = "100";
$("input[name='tmcp_textfield_6']").val(Pak);
```

Comment: Have you imported jquery into the page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971394/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined)

Comment: WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find the Working Script here, I think you should switch quotes, where double quotes use single, and where single quotes, use double.

```js
var Pak = "Test"
$('input[name="tmcp_textfield_6"]').val(Pak)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tmcp_textfield_6">
```

Be sure you've also included the jquery file to whatever page you need it to work on